# Java - Reading numbers from text file, and sorting them makes negative numbers turn to zero

Tags: java

I have a double array

```java
double[] numbers = new double[1000];
int size = 0;
```

I then read the numbers from the text file `numbers.txt`

```
input = new Scanner(new FileReader("numbers.txt"));
output= new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("sorted.txt"));

while (input.hasNext()) {
    numbers[size] = input.nextDouble();
    size = size + 1;
    if (size == 1000) break;
```

And then sort them using following:

```
numbers = Arrays.stream(numbers)
                .boxed()
                .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
                .mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue)
                .toArray();
```

And write them to file `sorted.txt`

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    output.println(numbers[i]);
```

When I try to sort an array that includes negative numbers, for example if `numbers.txt` 
contains `5 -3 1 -4`, then `sorted.txt` will contain `5 1 0 0`.

I'm relatively a beginner in Java and I'm not sure why this happens.
When I use `Array.sort(numbers,0,size)` it works well, but I'm trying to sort them in descending order, as this method sorts them in ascending order.

Comment: Couple of suggestions to debug the code. First, check if the numbers are still negative after you sort. If not, something is going wrong here, right? You've five operations mixed here. Put each one of them in a separate statement and check where the negative numbers are becoming zero.

Comment: You are sorting the entire array `numbers` which initially contains 1,000 elements, all of which are 0 (zero). Why not use a `java.util.List` to store the numbers read from the file?

Comment: You can also sort the array in reverse order with: 
Arrays.sort(numbers, Collections.reverseOrder());

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `Arrays.stream(numbers)` streams the entire array ... including the parts of the array that you didn't put values into.  Those parts will contain `0.0`.

So what is happening is:

1. You read 4 numbers from the file into the array.  This gives you:

   ```
     [5.0, -3.0, 1.0, -4.0, 0.0, 0.0, .....  0.0]
   ```
2. You sort the array in reverse order:

   ```
     [5.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, ..... 0.0, -1.0, -3.0]
   ```
3. Print out the first 4 elements of the array.

   ```
     [5.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
   ```

There are various approaches to solving this, including:

- Use an `ArrayList<Double>` instead of a `double[]`.
- Pre-initialize all array elements with (say) `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY`
- Use `Arrays.copy` to copy the subarray you need before sorting.
- Rewrite the stream code to select elements `0` to `size - 1` before sorting; e.g.

  ```
   numbers = Arrays.stream(numbers).limit(size). ....
  ```

Comment: @Rup - Thanks.  I'd forgotten there was an elegant way to do that.